# EOF Exception when using Hadoop custom data type

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am first time using custom data type in Hadoop. Here is my code :

Custom data Type:

```
public class TwitterData implements Writable {

private Long id;
private String text;
private Long createdAt;

public TwitterData(Long id, String text, Long createdAt) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.text = text;
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

public TwitterData() {
    this(new Long(0L), new String(), new Long(0L));
}

@Override
public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("In readFields...");
    id = in.readLong();
    text = in.readLine();
    createdAt = in.readLong();
}

@Override
public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("In write...");
    out.writeLong(id);
    out.writeChars(text);
    out.writeLong(createdAt);
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public Long getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

public void setCreatedAt(Long createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}
}
```

Mapper :

```
public class Map extends Mapper<Object, BSONObject, Text, TwitterData>{

@Override
public void map(Object key, BSONObject value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    BSONObject user = (BSONObject) value.get("user");
    String location = (String) user.get("location");

    TwitterData twitterData = new TwitterData((Long) value.get("id"),
            (String) value.get("text"), (Long) value.get("createdAt"));

    if(location.toLowerCase().indexOf("india") != -1) {
        context.write(new Text("India"), twitterData);
    } else {
        context.write(new Text("Other"), twitterData);
    }
}
}
```

Main Job Code :

```
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(TwitterData.class);
```

I throws this exception after Mapping process. I am sucked why it shows this error. Can anyone please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write characters, and you read lines. These are two different serialization processes.

What you need to do, is doing this:

```
@Override
public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    id = in.readLong();
    text = in.readUTF();
    createdAt = in.readLong();
}

@Override
public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.writeLong(id);
    out.writeUTF(text);
    out.writeLong(createdAt);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I worked for me. So what is the use of readLine() when we don't have writeLine()? Similarly for writeChars()..

Comment: @AbhendraSingh when you read from a textfile and read line by line for example. Writing a line would be writing UTF + '\n'.